# POST with Android Retrofit return null

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to send a request to my webservice ,
base on my json I have Example class . While a send request noting return .

```
   public void sendPost(String icon_url, String id) {
    mAPIService.savePost(icon_url, id).enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse(response.body().toString());
                Log.i("mhs", "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("mhs1", "Unable to submit post to API.");
        }
    });
}


@POST("/TranslateLongText")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Example> savePost(
        @Field("fromText") String fromText,
        @Field("targetLanguage") String targetLanguage);
```

and in onclick of my button i just call :

```
      submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



                sendPost("قارسی", "en");

        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe it is enough to set @FormUrlEncoded for your retrofit call and you can delete @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")

Comment: @BanMarkovic I omit this , but nothing is changed

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your string "قارسی", maybe the server cannot handle this format. Did you try with regular UTF-8 string?

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class BaseRetrofit {

public final static String WebApiAndSignalrUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:81/";

private static volatile LoginController loginController;

private static volatile MobilController mobilController;

public static synchronized LoginController getLoginController() {
    if (loginController == null) {
        loginController = createRetrofit().create(LoginController.class);
    }
    return loginController;
}

public static synchronized MobilController getMobilController() {
    if (mobilController == null) {
        mobilController = createRetrofit().create(MobilController.class);
    }
    return mobilController;
}

private static Retrofit createRetrofit() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(s -> Log.e("Request", s));
    loggingInterceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);



    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .addNetworkInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(WebApiAndSignalrUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

}

```
@Headers({"User-Agent: AndroidClient"})
@POST("Mobil/InsertDbErrorTracer")
Observable<String> InsertDbErrorTracer(@Header("Authorization") String Token, @Body List<DbErrorTracer> dbErrorTracers);



 public String uploadLogServer(List<DbErrorTracer> dbErrorTracers) {
    return BaseRetrofit
            .getMobilController()
            .InsertDbErrorTracer(getWebapiToken(), dbErrorTracers)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .blockingFirst();
}
```